# Trying to determine data throughput with my ADB shell commands

Tags: android, performance, shell

I am running some throughput tests with my phone connected, and I am trying to determine my average bandwidth. It would be some value in Mbits/sec

And I run the following commands on server side (where phone is connected on my PC) :

```
adb shell setprop android.telephony.apn-restore 10000000; 
export PATH=/data/busybox:$PATH#; 
export PATH=/data:$PATH#; 
chmod 777 /data/iperf
adb shell /data/iperf -s -p 5199 -B 172.20.184.121  -u  -i 1 
adb shell exit
exit
```

where `172.20.184.121` is my device's IP.

On the client side I have this :

```
iperf -c 172.20.184.121 -p 5199 -u -b 300M -t 60 -i 1
```

Now, what I have done is, I wrote those adb shell commands above into a small .bat file and I call that bat file and tried to pipe it's output to a .txt file so that I could get the output of the actual UDP transfer. I want to see the bandwidth etc. I call my `adbcommands.bat` using a system command from my Perl script. So my script would start the batch file like this on command prompt :

`start adbcommands.bat > output.txt`

But I am not getting anything in my .txt file. The file is empty. As you can see the last instruction was `exit`, so the new command window which opens to run the adb shell commands will close by itself, and I was hoping when it does close, my .txt file would have the data transfer info. Nope.

So, then I tried using the `tee.exe` command like this :

`start adbcommands.bat | tee output.txt`

Still nothing. So now I am out of bullets and want some help. Does anybody have some idea how I could get the throughput info?

---

For those curious, if I didn't pipe the output to a file, and if I run the above `adbcommands.bat` file, the output looks like this :

```
adb shell /data/iperf -s -p 5115 -B 172.20.184.121  -u  -i 1
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on UDP port 5115
Binding to local address 172.20.184.121
Receiving 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  224 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 172.20.184.121 port 5115 connected with 172.20.98.85 port 51948
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec   148 KBytes  1.21 Mbits/sec   7.762 ms 38211/38314 (88%)
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec   159 KBytes  1.31 Mbits/sec   5.820 ms  743/  854 (87%)
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec   159 KBytes  1.31 Mbits/sec   6.762 ms  756/  867 (87%)
.....
.....
[  3]  0.0-166.2 sec  54.5 MBytes  2.75 Mbits/sec   7.700 ms 4506398/4545298 (99%)
```

What I need is in that very last line : `2.75 Mbits/sec`. That's my throughput. I am trying to pipe to a .txt file so that my script could parse it and find that value.

Comment: what are you trying to do with `export PATH=/data/busybox:$PATH#; `, I mean why are you using `#` at the end?

Comment: also, every time you run `adb shell` it's a different shell, so `adb shell exit` does nothing.

Comment: I'm wondering if `iperf` might be printing on stderr instead of stdout. Try `start adbcommands.bat 2> output.txt`

Comment: @Diego Torres Milano : The $PATH was for a perl variable I was appending as I created my .bat file using my perl script.. I forgot to remove that above when I copy pasted. Also, I gave different adb shell commands since it's a batch file. When I use `&&` symbol to stitch many commands I sometimes get an error.


@janos : I tried that :(. Didn't get an output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what you describe in your question, if you run

```
adb shell /data/iperf -s -p 5199 -B 172.20.184.121  -u  -i 1 > output.txt
```

you should be able to redirect the output to the file.

Comment: how did you install iperf on the phone? how could you run iperf as a command?